# If we have 3 bins and 5 balls, how many ways can we assign balls to bins?

Tags: combinatorics

In this case, the occupancy theorem gives me a result of ${7 \choose 2} = 21$, but working it out by hand gives me $56$. I think the difference is that the order of the bins matters in my case.

Following the same type of formula, I'm guessing that the general formula that would give a result of $56$ with $n=3$ and $p=5$ is $C(n+p,n)$, but I have no idea why that would be the case. It doesn't fit with any of the occupancy formulas. The one my textbook gives is $C(n+p-1,n-1)$, but this is clearly incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is not homework per se, but its a very minor part of a course project in heuristic search. I just need a formula to find the worst-case search time (i.e. when all combinations are tried) against my heuristic algorithm.

Edit: The difference, as I just figured out, is that I'm interested in all of the allocations with <= 5 balls, not just with all 5 balls allocated.

Comment: The calculation $\binom72$ **is** for the case in which the order of the bins does matter, but the balls are indistinguishable. Perhaps you could show us at least some of the $56$ cases that you’re counting.

Comment: I think I just figured out the difference: I was counting all combinations that give a sum <= 5, as the algorithm has to search all of these combinations.

Comment: Don't "follow formulas" --- think it through!

Comment: Press shift + enter for multiline in comments. But it doesn't work well with pure text. Works wonders for display style math, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using at most $5$ balls, then you’re looking at

$$\sum_{n=0}^5\binom{n+2}2\;.$$

More generally, if you have $r$ bins and a maximum of $n$ balls, you’re looking at

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+r-1}{r-1}$$

assignments. A handy identity, formula $(10)$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients), takes care of this sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{n+r}r\;.$$

In your case that’s $\dbinom{5+3}3=56$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @mike: You’re welcome! (I’m about to add a reference for that identity.)